# asp.net gridview edit template http link

Tags: asp.net, gridview, label, bind

I have a label within an Edit Template for a gridview which goes like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblProjectID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Project_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
```

I would like to turn that label text into a http link like so:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblProjectID" runat="server" Text='<a href=http://intranet/?<%# Bind("Project_ID") %>> <%# Bind("Project_ID") %></a>'></asp:Label>
```

So the link would look something like `http://intranet/?Project_ID`

But that syntax is incorrect. What is the correct way to write that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you can do on your `Label` tag.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>

        <a href='<%# String.Format("http://intranet/?Project_ID={0}", Eval("Project_ID")) %>'><%# Eval("Project_ID")%></a>

     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I get server tag is not well formed. Some sort of typo somewhere in that string.

Comment: This is what I have and I still get server tag is not well formed:  <asp:Label ID="lblProjectID" runat="server" Text="<a href='<%# String.Format("http://intranet/?Project_ID={0}", Eval("Project_ID")) %>'>"></asp:Label> the link on the page is showing as this '>' target=_blank>'>

Comment: you are right....not sure why its not setting inside the text property of Label...anyways as you just want to set the link...i did suggest you my updated answer...i just removed the label tag and everything seems fine now....tried and tested...:)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be a link... then just use a link, not a label:

```
<a href='http://intranet/?<%# Eval("Project_ID") %>'><%# Eval("Project_ID")%></a>
```

or same thing with `HyperLinkField` (if you want to use it as a column and not inside `EditItemTemplate`:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="Project_ID" DataNavigateUrlFields="Project_ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="http://intranet/?{0}" />
```